# How to use PCA to find best portfolio replication

Tags: replication, pca

I have an exposure to 3 products. I have another 12 tradable products that I can use for hedging myself.  I have the correlation matrix between the 15 (12+3) products.
How can I use PCA to find the best hedge (selection among the 12 tradable products) ?

Thank you for anyone who could help.

Comment: You should find eigenvectors of the covariance matrix and then pick lets say 3 eigenvectors that explain most of the variance. Then you should bump risk factors by each eigenvector and calculate change in NPV of each trade after bumping. Then find linear combination of trades that neutralise NPV of portfolio for each scenario. If you need more thorough answer let me know and I will provide one.